# Change Date and group by Fiscal Month End

Tags: sql, group-by, calendar, union

I have created the following table (via UNION ALL):

```
ID        Date         Hour   Weight    Fiscal
AAA       1/27/2009     0      10         0
AAA       1/30/2009     0      20         0
AAA       2/14/2009     0      10         0
AAA       2/18/2009     0      20         0
AAA       2/27/2009     0      20         0
AAA       2/28/2009     0      20         0
AAA       1/14/2009     10     0          0
AAA       2/14/2009     20     0          0
AAA       2/16/2009     10     0          0
AAA       2/25/2009     10     0          0
AAA       2/26/2009     10     0          0
AAA       3/3/2009          20     0          0
NULL          0                 0      0          1/28/2009
NULL          0                 0      0          2/27/2009
NULL          0                 0      0          3/29/2009
```

And I would like to retrieve:

```
    ID      Date        Hour    Weight
    AAA     1/28/2009   10  10
    AAA     2/27/2009   50  50
    AAA     3/29/2009   20  20
```

It should first convert the DATE column to the next Fiscal month end FISCAL (for example 1/27/2007 -> 1/28/2009, 1/30/2009 -> 2/27/2009, etc.) and then group by that value.

I was able to use:

```
    SELECT  ID
    ,       left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)
    ,       date, 111),7) as Date
    ,       round(sum(Hours),0) as Hours
    ,       round(sum(Weight),0) as Weight
    FROM    ...
    GROUP   BY ID
    ,       left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date, 111),7)
    ORDER   by ID ASC
    ,       left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date, 111),7) ASC
```

But that just groups by *calendar* dates, not according to the Fiscal month ends I have in the *FISCAL* column.

Comment: What DB Engine are you using here? Also can you post the SQL that is returning the first output.

Comment: You need to clarify this question. Fiscal in the above table is 0 for the first 12 entries, so how are those dates computed? Are Hour and Weight somehow related to the fiscal month computation? Are we joining multiple rows together to compute a single row (e.g. joining AAA entries in multiple rows to determine the actual fiscal month)? Reduce to the basic problem...

Comment: The first step is to get the data into two separate tables.  You want the second table to represent the fiscal months, with a start date and an end date for each one.  Sorting that out from the UNION ALL mess above is silly - much too much like hard work.  With that table available, the grouping becomes pretty straight-forward; you group by the fiscal end and join by 'dateval BETWEEN fiscal_start AND fiscal_end'; the inclusive range of BETWEEN/AND is very helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not union the fiscal dates into your table. But with the table as you have now, you could first create a table (using WITH, so no special priviliges are necessary) with the fiscal 'periods' and join this table with your main table.

I called your Table SO. I also had to rename your columns to cHour and CDate because in Oracle at least Date is a reserved word.
You could very probably create the table 'main' and the table 'fiscal' directly from your source tables to speed things up:

```
with fiscal_part as (
            select fiscal
            from   SO
            where  fiscal is not null)
,    fiscal as (
            select fb.fiscal         fiscal_begin
            ,      min(fe.fiscal)    fiscal_end
            from   fiscal_part fb right join 
                   fiscal_part fe
                on fe.fiscal > fb.fiscal
            group by fb.fiscal)
,    main as (
            select *
            from   SO
            where  fiscal is null)
select main.ID
,      fiscal.fiscal_end
,      sum(main.cHour)
,      sum(main.weight)
from   main
join   fiscal on main.cdate >= coalesce(fiscal.fiscal_begin, main.cdate)
             and main.cdate <  fiscal.fiscal_end
group by main.ID
,      fiscal.fiscal_end
order by fiscal.fiscal_end
```

Also note that your sample data has an error; the weight for your last period should be 40 (the rows with dates 2/27 and 2/28).